# What action after "submit"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails after pressing submit button in "new" I automatically come to "create" (similar after "edit" to "update"). All my params getting in "new" available in "create". This is by default. 
If I have "export" instead of "new" and "process_export" instead of "create" - how reach similar effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right than you don't want to send the form to the default `create` action but rather to another, in your example to a `process_export` action.

All you have to do is to create a route in your `routes.rb` and set a custom form action url.

**Example:**

routes.rb

```
get '/process_export' => 'your_controller#export'    # replace `your_controller` with your controller name
post '/process_export' => 'your_controller#process_export', as: :process_export
```

In your `export` view:

```
<%= form_for :resource, url: process_export_path do |f| %>  <!-- Replace resource with your proper resource -->
  <!-- Your form here -->
<% end %>
```

But I highly recommend you to observe the conventions of REST. It makes your live a lot easier.

Here are two resources which explain it in more detail:

- Rails Routing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
- Form Helpers: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: Thanks, Tobias, for attempt to help, but I still can't get working example. As part of admin service I would like to export and import important tables of the project. I created controller, put to 'new' action select box for choose the table and after submit put in 'create' process of export. Now I have to do the same for import. I see 2 ways: put second submit button in 'new' or use 'new2' and 'create2' actions. I selected second way but after submit in 'new2' I don't come automatically to 'create2'. I understand that the solution is in adding line to 'routes.rb' but have problem with syntax.

Comment: I would highly recommend you to create two controllers for import and export because these are two different actions which also behave differently. So for example an `ImportController` and `ExportController`. In this way none of them get in the way of the other and it's pretty well scalable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is easy! You are right: better to find alternative solution instead of investigations of avoiding of default options.

Comment: If this is an open source project you can send me the source and I can take a look and give you maybe some recommendations. Otherwise good luck and keep learning!

Answer (score 0):

Rails follow the `Convention over Configuration` concept . The 7 methods of `REST` are automatically called from the controller when a similar `request` comes in the Rails 4 . For ex : the `GET` request will call new method , `POST` will call create method , `DELETE` will call destroy method etc .

Now , if you are creating a `custom method` in your `controller` like `export` and if you want to call it after the clicking on the `submit` button , you have to set `routes` accordingly in the `routes.rb` file . Which can be done as :

```
post "/chats" => "chats#export"
```

Here , `chats` is the `controller` and `export` is the method in that controller which you want to call on the `submit` action.

You can do :

```
$ > rails g scaffold Controller_name
```

and this will generate all the 7 REST methods in your controller automatically  and similar routes are generated which you can check by doing :

```
$ > rake routes
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I don't exactly understand what means /:text. In your terminology:

Comment: @sergey : edited my answer . thanx for marking it out. :)

Comment: Thanks. I don't exactly understand what means /:text. So: My controller: 'chats', my action is 'export' and my action after submit in 'export' is 'process_export'. Certainly I have to write in routes.rb get "/chats/export" => "chats#export" and now (your suggestion) I have to add extra post "/chats/export" => "chats#process_export". Is it correct?

Comment: @sergey : `chats` controller is just an example that i have explained . you have to replace your `controlle`r in place of chats.

Comment: I understand that chat is example. The most difficult thing here how to connect two my actions (export and process_export). In your explanation it was not obvious (may be misprint). And I only try to detailed: should it be post "/chats/export" => "chats#process_export" ? or I understood something wrong?

Comment: You mean to say , on a single post you want to call two different actions in the controller ?

Comment: May be more than two. Ok, I just renamed my 'new' action to 'export' and 'create' to 'process_export'. Now I can't automatically come to 'process_export' after submit. What I should do to reach the same effect?

Comment: rename the route as `post`  `'controller_name/param' => 'controller_name#process_export'`. And it's still confusing  to understand what you want to do exactly.